# Filter data by condition with multiple values in Google Sheets without using a FILTER function

Tags: google-sheets

Do multiple filter conditions get separated by commas?

[image: Filter data by condition with multiple values in Google Sheets without using a FILTER function]

Update, I've set the Filter by condition > Custom formula to `=not(regexmatch(N:N, "(?i)design(?i)|(?i)av(?i)|(?i)AV(?i)"))` but companies containing the string `AV` are still visible.

Answer (score 1):

Using that formula you came up with, try using as in conditional formatting: as if you were applying it to the first cell of the filtered range. If you have a heading, and you're filtering from N2:

```
=not(regexmatch(N2, "(?i)design(?i)|(?i)av(?i)|(?i)AV(?i)"))
```

In fact, you could simplify it since you have multiple redundant (?i):

```
=not(regexmatch(N2, "(?i)[design|av]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Already answered [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88767/8277):

> You can filter using a regular expression. Use the options Filter by condition > Custom formula is...

```
=not(regexmatch(N:N, "(?i)facebook|pinterest|twitter"))
```

I had to click `Clear` under `Filter by values` (to remove the old filter) then open the filter again and click `Select All` under `Filter by values`.